# Why can Visual Studio 2015CE Project crush with error "notMarshalable occuring"

Tags: c#, marshalling, visual-studio-2015

I have Project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. When i start project, it works, all good.
If i close my running program, it shows me error `notMarshalable occuring`.

`Managed Debugging Assistant 'NotMarshalable' has detected a problem in 'myProjectPath.App.vshost.exe'.`

There is no error on others PC with different VS.

How to fix this thing?

Comment: This warning is normally turned off.  You probably screwed up your debugging settings.  Debug > Exceptions > Managed Debugging Assistants > NonMarshalable.

Comment: If turning off this warning, error `program has stopped working vshost32.exe` occures